# Power BI Python create new columns by parsing existing column with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create new columns by parsing an existing column using regex. I want to parse key_set column and create key1, key2,key3,key4 columns and populate data if the key exists in the key_set. some keys may not be exist or may not be in the same order. That's why I am trying to achieve this with regular exp. I have to do it using **findall** like shown below because I will use this approach in **Power BI**. Any help is appreciated.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

d = {'name': ['John', 'Mark', 'Oz'],
     'key_set': ['https://test.com/direct/?key1=value344&key2=value566&key3=value577&key4=value888',
                 'https://test.com/direct/?key1=value113&key2=value332',
                 'https://test.com/direct/?key1=value111&key2=value222&key3=value333&key4=value444'] }

dataset = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(dataset)

keywords = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']
any_keyword = '|'.join(map(re.escape, keywords))
regex = "(" + any_keyword + ")=(.+?)(?=(?:" + any_keyword + ")=|$)"
# test_str='https://test.com/direct/?key1=value111&key2=value222&key3=value333&key4=value444'
# print([m.group().replace('&', '') for m in re.finditer(regex, test_str)])

print('')
print('====================================')
print('')

# APPROACH: This is how I test it and it works up to a point.
dataset['test1'] = dataset['key_set'].str.findall(regex)
print(dataset)

# I need to use the same approach and create one column per key attribute. How can I use above example and use it below.

# dataset['key1'] = ****
# dataset['key2'] = ****
# dataset['key3'] = ****
# dataset['key4'] = ****
```

Comment: What is the problem/question? What is not working?

Comment: I provided the code to show what I have achieved so far. 'test1' shows as a column in PowerBI table with this code. My question is how can refine the regular expression further to be able to parse key_set for each key.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def get_val( pattern, x ):
    """
    :param pattern: Regex pattern to match.
    :param x: String to search.
    :returns: Value if found, else None.
    """
    match = re.search( pattern, x )
    if match is None:
        return None
    
    return match.group( 2 )


for kn in range( 1, 5 ):
    key = f'key{kn}'  # key name

    # serach pattern ending with & or end of line
    pattern = f'({key})=(.*?)(?:&|$)'

    # apply get_val function over key_set for each key name
    df[ key ] = df[ 'key_set' ].apply( lambda x: get_val( pattern, x ) )
```

You can also use [`funtools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to create the function for `apply` if speed is an issue.

Comment: This works like a charm on PyCharm. Can you please see my answer below. I couldn't paste it here under your comment. I accepted your answer. It does what I want but PowerBI doesn't like it for some reason.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unfamiliar with PowerBI, however it may be worth asking a new question specifially for help with that.

Comment: Sorted it out with some workarounds.. Thank you so much!